# Hegel's “the worse for the facts!”

Tags: hegel

This [story](http://www.crvp.org/book/Series01/I-23/appendix_ii.htm) is often mentioned, but without references. Was that a true story? Did Hegel indeed say this -- “the worse for the facts!” -- when somebody told him "your theory contradicts the facts!"? Or this was just a joke? Does anybody know a reference to the original source?

Comment: Huxley's quote express something quite different, than Hegel's.
Huxley feel sad, maybe it is kind of nostalgy, because his theory got disproved by single experimental fact.
Hegel reacts just opposite - he rejects empirical evidence contradicting his theory.

Answer (score 3):

See the paper *Hegel and the Seven Planets* (1992), by Edward Craig & Michael Hoskin, in
Journal for the History of Astronomy, Vol.23, NO. 3/AUG, P.208, 1992.

You can search on the web : Hegel and the Seven Planets.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! Does it cointain a reference to the source?

Comment: Yes; the first page of the article concern the "so said" error contained in Hegel's *Dissertatio philosophica de orbitis planetarum*, published as docent thesis, where Hegel had "demontrated" that the number of planets cannot exceed the number of seven. This happens in the same years when the astronomer Piazzi discovered a new planet. Th papar's authors suggest that there is no place in Hegel's thesis that support such a reading.

Comment: Mauro, excuse me, I think this is a misunderstanding! That was my fault, I am actually looking for the evidenses that Hegel indeed said this: "the worse for the facts!" I'll edit my question!

Comment: Search in http://mathforum.org/kb/ sub voce : Math Forum » Discussions » Inactive » Historia-Matematica Topic: [HM] Hegel and seven planets .

Comment: Mauro, I still think that we do not understand each other. It is not important for me whether Hegel indeed claimed that the number of planets can't exceed 7 - I believe that this is true, I don't need supplementary evidences for this. I am asking about something else: whether he ever pronounced this phrase, "worse for the facts". That is the question for me.

Comment: Searching on the web, the results point to an episode during a lesson about history, without detailed references; so I think it can be difficult to find them (if any). It can be useful traying to search into some old biographical sources, like Karl Rosenkranz, *Georg Wilhelm Friedrich Hegels Leben* (1844).

Comment: Yes, that is what I am talking about... Perhaps, somebody knows where this is exactly?

Comment: Theres a similar story about Einstein when  he was asked how he would react if Eddingtons experiments contradicted his theory.

Comment: I believe Thomas Huxley said something similar - "A beautiful theory killed by a nasty ugly little fact."

Answer (score 1):

Georg Lukacs, the Hungarian ideolog of Marxism, attributed this to Fichte (quoted by Redner in his Malign Masters :48) but with no reference.